# Thick client session management and security

Tags: java, authentication, ssl, encryption, passwords

I want to develop a thick client app (instead of using jsp/server side) which I will provide a login panel upon launching of my app. I am not sure whether it is the correct approach (in terms of security) so would like some comments.

Authentication will be through a back end database. That is, I create the user at the database level and my thick client app will authenticate with database using the provided user id and password. Is this method safe enough? or do I need a real session/password management api to do this?

How do I keep sessions in a thick client app like this? Also, if I want to encryption traffic between my app and the database server, should i just use JSSE or similar? Is there a way to encrypt data instead of the communication channel? I believe my database server need to also be able to decrypt my encrypted data.

Comment: I can see that you are asking 5 questions here. Perhaps you should refine what it is that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I create the user at the database level and my thick client app will authenticate with database using the provided user id and password. Is this method safe enough?

Yes, provided you do as follows:

1. Hash the password in the database, rather than encrypt it.
2. Validate the user by querying the database `SELECT count(*) FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME=? AND PASSWORD=MD5(?)` or whatever hash algorithm you use. Note that this technique deliberately doesn't tell you whether the username or the password was wrong, so as to avoid any possibility of leaking that information to an attacker. The idea is that it returns either 1 or 0.

> or do I need a real session/password management api to do this?

Not really.

> How do I keep sessions in a thick client app like this?

If you mean a session that persists between logins, keep it in the database. If you just mean a session that lasts between login and logout, just keep it in an object that is released on logout.

> Also, if I want to encryption traffic between my app and the database server, should i just use JSSE or similar?

Yes.

> Is there a way to encrypt data instead of the communication channel?

The database can do it with encryption functions.

> I believe my database server need to also be able to decrypt my encrypted data?

What encrypted data? If you mean the stuff transmitted over SSL, it will be decrypted automatically.